# What is MSVC equivalent to gcc's -Wundef?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, g++, compiler-warnings, cl.exe

I'd like cl.exe to report warning in case undefined macro is encountered in preprocessor expression compiling c/c++ source. Like g++ -Wundef. Is it available?
Going through the list of all compiler warnings at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfahxw6k.aspx  is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVC's compiler option `/wd4668` (to disable warning "C4668") should be equivalent to `-Wundef`, according to the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dt9kyhy.aspx.  [Based on the comment to the original question.]

Unfortunately, this warning is unusable, because it produces a lot of warnings in system header files.  Unlike GCC/Clang, MSVC does not appear to have the ability to ignore warnings in system header files.

Comment: A warning is not the same as a compiler option.  To make this an answer, you should give the command-line option that enables this particular warning.  (The warning number was appropriate as a comment, it isn't a complete answer)

Comment: Fixed by mentioning `/wd4668`, though I haven't tested it.